# Why are communications merely jammed?

Tags: robopocalypse

In *[Robopocalypse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robopocalypse)*, Archos and his army of "Robs" predictably blocks communications between the humans.

> Lurker, however, identifies that satellite communications are being jammed via a signal from the British Telecom Tower and destroys the source of the signal.

With this completed,

> humans are now able to communicate long distances again,

thus turning the tide of the war.

Since the groups we follow through the book are scattered across the globe, we can infer that

> this single jammed signal was responsible for much, if not all of the blocked communications.

Is there a reason I've overlooked as to why Archos didn't just destroy

> the British Telecom Tower or the satellite being used for communications - either before or after Lurker's mission?

Answer (score 3):

Archos is using the satellites to communicate with his own troops as well as observing the disposition of human forces.

Lurker's plan is to either destroy the BT tower's fibre-optic links (thus ending the jamming signal that Archos is using to block the human's ground communication uplinks) or to take over the tower's control systems, potentially allowing them to counteract the precursor virus and disable some or all of Archos' robot minions.

Either way, it's a win-win for the humans.

> “The fiber,” Lurker whispers. “We’ll want to get down to the fiber.
>   Best-case, we hijack it and send a signal for all the robots to jump
>   into the river. Worst case, we blast the jammer and free up the
>   communications satellites.”

later

> The destruction of the London fiber hub broke the Rob stranglehold on
>   satellite communications long enough to allow humankind to regroup.
>   Lurker never seemed like a very pleasant guy, and I can’t say I would
>   have enjoyed meeting him, but the kid was a hero. I know this because
>   in the moment before the British Telecom Tower exploded, Lurker
>   recorded a fifteen-second message that saved humankind